# AirPlay Meta Data on Apple TV from Mac App

Tags: macos, mirroring, airplay

I am using the class MPNowPlayingInfoCenter to set a song's meta data in an iOS app. How do I set it in an OS X app?

Answer (score 0):

- Before Mountain Lion (OS X 10.8), there was no official 3rd party support for AirPlay, although iTunes has integrated it for a long time.
- Mountain Lion added a control to allow the user to choose the audio output. However, this happens outside of your app and there are still no public APIs to control AirPlay.

There are several 3rd party implementations of AirPlay. The most famous being [AirFoil](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/). They have a [public API](http://weblog.rogueamoeba.com/2011/04/06/airfoil-integration/) to display metadata. However, it relies on AppleScript, which doesn't work with the new App Store sandbox.

This is the big picture. Feel free to ask more if you need clarifications.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
But I need the solution for publishing to Mac App Store.